# Counting how many RecyclerView items the user has seen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to track how much a scroll is needed for my users in my app. So I would like to count the amount of recyclerview items that have been displayed in a user's screen before he takes some action.

Is there a way to calculate this? Maybe working with visible items & scroll position?

I am using a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: Would counting the amount onBindViewHolder is called suffice? This isn't exactly the amount that's displayed, but I can imagine it gets close.

Comment: not really, what if you scroll down and then up, then you would be miscounting

Comment: Then count them for every item separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out a solution:

```
var oldFirstPos = -1
var oldLastPos = -1
var totalItemsViewed = 0

with(rvBasic) {
    layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
    adapter = BasicRecyclerViewAdapter(layoutInflater, items)

    addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView?, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val currFirstPos = gridLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            val currLastPos = gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

            totalItemsViewed += when (oldFirstPos) {
                -1 -> currLastPos - currFirstPos + 1
                else -> when {
                    dy > 0 -> Math.abs(currLastPos - oldLastPos) //scrolling to bottom
                    else -> Math.abs(currFirstPos - oldFirstPos) //scrolling to top
                }
            }

            oldLastPos = currLastPos
            oldFirstPos = currFirstPos

            Log.d("Items viewed", "items viewed: ${totalItemsViewed}")
        }
    })
}
```

My idea was the following: Grab the current `firstVisibleCompletelyVisiblePosition` and `lastCompletelyVisiblePosition` and then calculate the delta of those positions since the last scroll depending on the scroll direction. The initial scroll is identified by setting the `oldFirstPos` to `-1` (`oldLastPos` could theoretically be any value), since the position in the `GridLayoutManager` starts at 0.

To identify the amount initially visible - and therefore viewed - items the following simple formula is needed: `currLastPos - currFirstPos + 1` (the `+1` is there since the position starts at 0).

When the user now scrolls to the bottom `dy gets greater than 0` and therefore the absolute change in the `lastPos` is important for us. The same applies when the scroll is in the opposite direction. Though, with the key difference, that now the absolute change in the `firstPos` is the change in the amount of visible items since the last `onScrolled` was triggered.

**Why is it important to adapt the position change calculation when the scroll direction changes?**

Lets assume you have 19 items in your Grid with a `spanCount of 4`, hence the last row will consist of 3 items. Scrolling down to it, the `totalItemsViewed` will count up to 19. Now when you scroll back up you will miss an item, because if you scroll a little bit upwards the `lastPos` will change from 19 to 16, but the `firstPos` will change from (depending on how many items are visible at a time on the display) 12 to 8. Now you have basically lost an item. If your `items % spanCount == 0` then you will be fine without adapting the change according to the scroll direction.

*Note: this solution only works with a vertical GridLayoutManager (horizontal is similar though)*

Comment: It is only increasing the counter

Answer (score 0):

As per @Rene Ferrari's answer i modified the code when scroll to top, you could do something like this in java:

```
private int oldFirstPos = -1, oldLastPos = -1,totalItemsViewed = 0;
rv.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                GridLayoutManager layoutManager = ((GridLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager());

                int currFirstPos = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                int currLastPos = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                if(oldFirstPos == -1){
                    totalItemsViewed += currLastPos - currFirstPos + 1;
                }else{
                    if(dy > 0){
                        totalItemsViewed += Math.abs(currLastPos - oldLastPos);
                    }else{
                        totalItemsViewed -= Math.abs(oldLastPos - currLastPos);
                    }
                }
                oldLastPos = currLastPos;
                oldFirstPos = currFirstPos;

                Log.e("totalItemsViewed",totalItemsViewed);
 }
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Pratik Saluja hope it helps.